# How to connect FlexemServer through Flexemclient by signalR client

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, signalr-client

As I'm new to signalR client and flexem server. I'm connecting flexemserver through flexem client with package **("FBoxClientDriver" and "FBoxClientDriver.Contract")**.
[image]

I'm referring flexem client with this url "https://docs.flexem.net/fbox/zh-cn/explain/index.html"

Here is my code for signalR client

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                       .WithUrl("******************************")
                       .Build();

        await connection.StartAsync();

        await connection.InvokeAsync("Start");
        await connection.InvokeAsync("StartAllDMonData");
        await connection.InvokeAsync("GetBoxGroups");

        connection.Closed += async (error) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
            await connection.StartAsync();
        };
     }
  }
```

Using SignalR client package

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client

I'm unable to connect to Flexem server and get the data. Connection state showing as connecting while debugging and However I'm unable to connect to flexem client through flexem server. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I suggest making your main method `async` and replacing all the `Task.Run` and `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` calls with `await`

Comment: @stuartd, Thank for correcting me. as you suggested edited the code.